# Adding HTML to the left of the existing contents of DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

I currently have a **div** in the bottom right portion of a page, and I want it to be fixed so that when a user scrolls, re-sizes, etc the **div** is always in the bottom right of the visible browser.  I have already done this:

HTML:

```
 <div id="chats-div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#chats-div
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

So far so good.  Now, using jQuery, I would like to add HTML to this div, and have it appear to the left of the contents already in the **div**, so I am trying this (from a button press):

jQuery:

```
$('#chats-div').prepend("<div style='height:100px;width:50px;border:1px;border-style:solid;background-color:White;'>Div Contents</div>");
```

However, each time I press the button, the new HTML is added above (on top of) the previous **div**, rather than to the left of it.

I am basically trying to re-create a gmail/facebook style chat.  I want to add a new chat window to the left of any existing chat windows, while keeping the whole chat section in the bottom right.  I know I am close, and have spent too much time trying to Google it/figure it out on my own.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just need to add `float: left;` to the div you create, as shown:

**CSS:**

```
.chat
{
   height:100px;
   width:50px;
   border:1px;
   border-style:solid;
   background-color:White; 
   float:left;             /*Added to make them float alongside each other. */
}
```

**Prepend function:**

```
$('#chats-div').prepend("<div class='chat'>Div Contents</div>");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/6eNqC/1/)

Comment: +1 Good One.
Though ill prefer it assigning a class to the div and then using css

Comment: I would highly recommend a class as well :) I'll update the demo for readability.

Comment: Updated an added a class as opposed to all that inline css :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a width to `#chats-div`? Maybe `100%`. And also `float` your new `div`s, or make them `display:inline`/`display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

lol oh wells... someone else has a better answer but for what it's worth.

```
$('#chats-div').prepend("<div style='position:absolute;right:"+$("#chats-div").children().length*100+"%;height:100px;width:50px;border:1px;border-style:solid;background-color:White;'>Div Contents</div>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xZLf5/